# Notify user from ViewModel and cancel navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a view that contains a list of items, a `TextBox` and a Save button. The `TextBox` is bound to a property of the currently selected item of the list. The `DataSource` of the list is bound to an `ObservableCollection<T>` in the ViewModel.
Now, when the user selects another item in the list and hasn't saved his changes to the `TextBox`, he should be asked whether or not he wants to discard the changes he made. The selected item in the list should only be changed if he answers this with yes.
The problem I have is this:
I need to implement the check for changes in the ViewModel, but I don't know where, as the ViewModel doesn't get notified, when the selected item is changing.

---

I came up with the following method, but it doesn't seem to be clean:
There is an event `SelectedItemsChanging` on the list. I could use the `EventToCommand` behavior and pass the `CancelEventArgs` as a parameter to the command. In the command, I check of the item was changed and if so, I could use the messenger to send a message the View listens for. The View will then show the confirmation dialog to the user and return the result back to ViewModel *somehow*. The ViewModel in turn sets the `Cancel` property of the event args to `true` if the user doesn't want to discard his changes.
This doesn't look clean to me, because it rips this simple functionality apart and smears it over three files, making it very hard to understand.
Are there any best practices for a scenario like this?

Comment: I think you need to handle this in the client-side.

Comment: What client side are you talking about? This is a windows application, not a web application.

Comment: @H.B.: Yes, it's a third party control that doesn't conform to the naming standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I came across the "Interaction Request" "pattern" as used by PRISM. This is basically the same solution I already lined out in my answer, just a little bit more sophisticated. That's what I am using now.

It works like this:

1. The ViewModel has a property of my custom interface `IInteractionRequest<TInteractionData>`. This interface only contains an event `Raised`.
2. In the View a behavior is bound to this property.

   ```
   <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
       <Interaction:NotificationMessageBoxBehavior
            SourceObject="{Binding NotificationRequest}" />
   </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
   ```

   The bound behavior (in the example `NotificationMessageBoxBehavior`) is what controls how the interaction request is handled. For example, in a Windows application this simply calls `MessageBox.Show`, but there might be an alternative implementation that works in Silverlight applications.
   The behaviors are all derived from a common base class that derives from [`Behavior<FrameworkElement>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff726531%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) and has a dependency property `SourceObject` of type `IInteractionRequest<TInteractionData>`. That's how the behavior and the interaction request are brought together: The behavior subscribes to the `Raised` event of the `SourceObject` and executes the interaction request when the event is raised.
3. The concrete implementation of the interaction data that is used in the request can contain a callback that is called after the request has been completed. This callback can have a parameter. Like this, the result of the interaction request can flow back to the ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

I would put Dirty checking on the model class.  Example below:

```
Public m_dirtyFields As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

Private Sub AddDirtyField(ByVal ColName As String, ByVal OrigValue As String)
    If Not m_dirtyFields.ContainsKey(ColName) Then
        m_dirtyFields.Add(ColName, OrigValue)
        OnPropertyChanged("IsDirty")
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub RemoveDirtyField(ByVal ColName As String)
    If m_dirtyFields.ContainsKey(ColName) Then
        m_dirtyFields.Remove(ColName)
    End If
    OnPropertyChanged("IsDirty")
End Sub

Private Sub OnAddress1Changing(ByVal value As String)
    If Not m_dirtyFields.ContainsKey("Address1") Then
        AddDirtyField("Address1", Address1)
    Else
        If m_dirtyFields("Address1") = value Then RemoveDirtyField("Address1")
    End If
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property IsDirty
    Get
        If _Initialized = False Then
            m_dirtyFields.Clear()
            _Initialized = True
        End If

        If m_dirtyFields.Count > 0 Then
            Return True
        Else : Return False
        End If
    End Get
End Property
```

The above example checks property values add them to a dictionary based on similarity of original value and returns Dirty based on items in the dictionary.

In your ViewModel, you can just check MyObject.IsDirty and if it is changed, pop up a message box asking the user to save (or not).

Additionally, you can have the Listbox disabled (so the user cant change records) while a record is dirty, but having a property on the ViewModel which advertizes the Dirty property of the SelectedItem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it looks like you didn't get my question. I have no problem with the dirty check itself. The problem is that there is no nice place to put that check. Disabling the list if the object is dirty is not an option.

Comment: If you have SelectedItem bound to a property in your ViewModel, you can make the check there just before the field gets set.  If the record is not dirty, then all the field to get set.  Otherwise, popup a dialog.  No event or EventToCommand necessary.

Comment: This doesn't work for two reasons: (1) I can't cancel the change of the selected item like this. (2) The popup should not be shown by the ViewModel but by the View.

Comment: In an instance when I had a list of items with a detail pane, I wrote a method which when the whole form closed checked the items to see if they were dirty, and then asked the user if they wished to save them.  This allowed the user to move back and forth through the collection of items at will regardless of whether they had saved or not.  Would something like that be acceptable?  Also, why can the popup not be created by the ViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

In MVVM for Windows 8 you can override PageModel.OnNavigating method.
http://w8mvvm.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=HandlePageNavigation&referringTitle=Documentation

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b287f569-7bf9-40d2-80f3-02c9945f1f33